# Scala, my generic function "findFirst" doesn 't work

Tags: java, scala, templates, generics, functional-programming

```
object FPSEx2_1 {

    def factorial(n: Int) : Int = {
        def go(n: Int, acc: Int) : Int = {
            if (n <= 0) acc
            else go(n-1, n*acc)
        }
        go(n, 1)
    }
    def fib(n: Int) : Int = {
        @annotation.tailrec
        def go(n:Int, prev: Int, cur: Int): Int = {
            if( n == 0) prev
            else go(n-1, cur, prev + cur)
        }
        go(n, 0,1)
    }
    def formatResult(name: String, n: Int, f:Int => Int) = {
        val msg = "The %s of %d is %d."
        msg.format(name, n, f(n))
    }

    def findFirst[A] (as: Array[A], p: A => Boolean): Int = {
        @annotation.tailrec
        def loop(n: Int) : Int = 
            if (n <= as.length) -1
            else if (p(as(n))) n
            else loop(n + 1)
        loop(0)
    }

    def isPear(p : String) : Boolean = {
        if (p == "pears") true
        else false
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
        println("hello word")
        println(factorial(3))
        println(fib(4))
        println(formatResult("factorial", 4, factorial))

        var fruit = Array("apples", "oranges", "pears")

        println(findFirst(fruit, isPear))  // this line prints -1, why doesn 't it work?
    }
}

println (findFirst (fruit, isPear))
```

The last and the marked line print -1, why  don 't they work?

Comment: Could you explain how it does not work? Reformulate and understandable question please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the condition in this line of your method `findFirst` is wrong:

```
if (n <= as.length) -1
```

You probably meant:

```
if (n >= as.length) -1
```